# How to filter specific number of records from each value present in clause in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

**HI
Scenario explained below:**
I have employee table with 100k records of all employees details who belongs to multiple departments

Employee table columns as below:
EmpNumber EmpName ,EmpAge, DepartmentNumer , DepartmentName.

**Note**: Hundreds of employees can belongs to each department.

**Question**:
How to filter only 10 employee records from each DepartmentNumer specified in where clause IN operator.

**Query**:
select * from Employee where DepartmentNumer in ( 'xxx' ,'yyyy') and  AND ROWNUM <= 10;

The Above query returning only 10 employee records who are belongs to the DepartmentNumer ='xxx' only (Because employee table have hundreds of records who belongs to DepartmentNumer =xxx, the above query not returning any records from DepartmentNumer ='yyyy'

In case of Where clause 'IN' matching, **How to filter 10 records from **each** DepartmentNumer** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by departmentnumber order by departmentnumber) as seqnum
      from employee e
      where DepartmentNumer in ('xxx', 'yyyy')
     ) e
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: Due to some limitations here, i don't want to use the stored procedure. Is their any we can achieve this through the standard SQL queries ?

Comment: i m using oracle db for above scenario

Comment: @Rk2020 . . . Nothing in this suggests a stored procedure.  This is standard SQL.

Comment: @Rk2020 That is standard SQL. ROW_NUMBER is just standard SQL analityc function from ANSI:SQL Standard.